# Maven-surefire-plugin with junit-platform-surefire-provider for Java 9 module

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-9, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a simple JPMS module. When I use the maven-surefire-plugin 2.20.1 everything is ok - my tests are executed:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

However, when I want to use newer versions of surefire (2.21.0 or 2.22.0) I get the following:

```
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was /bin/sh -c cd "/home/project" && /opt/jdk-9/bin/java '@/home/project/target/surefire/surefireargs4438382394951202560' '/home/project/target/surefire' 2018-09-13T13-42-05_435-jvmRun1 surefire4870497011802680670tmp surefire_015850140770716473411tmp
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was /bin/sh -c cd "/home/project" && /opt/jdk-9/bin/java '@/home/project/target/surefire/surefireargs4438382394951202560' '/home/project/target/surefire' 2018-09-13T13-42-05_435-jvmRun1 surefire4870497011802680670tmp surefire_015850140770716473411tmp
Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
Process Exit Code: 1
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
-> [Help 1]
```

And in surefire-reports I see the following:

```
# Created at 2018-09-13T13:42:07.587
Error: Could not find or load main class Projects..home.project.m2.repository.org.eclipse.persistence.javax.persistence.2.2.0.javax.persistence-2.2.0.jar:.home.project..m2.repository.org.eclipse.persistence.org.eclipse.persistence.core.2.7.0.org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar:.home.project..m2.repository.org.slf4j.slf4j-api.1.7.25.slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar ...

# Created at 2018-09-13T13:42:07.588
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /home/project//m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax/persistence/2/2/0/javax/persistence-2/2/0/jar:/home/project//m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org/eclipse/persistence/core/2/7/0/org/eclipse/persistence/core-2/7/0/jar:/home/project//m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1/7/25/slf4j-api-1/7/25/jar ...
```

How to fix/explain it? Is this a bug or I have mistake somewhere?

Comment: Use maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.0 which support JUnit 5 directly.. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in path building. See this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1568) and my first comment to it.

Comment: *Apache Maven Surefire Plugin 3.0.0-M2 Released* where this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.0 which support JUnit 5 directly..

See also the documentation how to use JUnit 5 with Maven Surefire Plugin version 2.22.0...

- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: might be related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1445 from the release notes(`2.21.0`) itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed all dependencies for testing except `    <dependency><groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId><artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId><version>5.3.0</version><scope>test</scope>  </dependency>` including dependencies of surefire-plugin. However, it didn't help. I still have the same error.